# Matlab calculating line parameter x for 10 layers in the given wavelength range

Tags: matlab

I know how to calculate the line parameter defined as x below for one layer, considering the given wavelength range 50 to 550 um. Now I want to repeat this calculation for all 10 layers. all the other parameters remain as a constant while temperature varies from layer 1 to 10.Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
wl=[100 200 300 400 500]; %5 wavelengths, 5 spectral lines 
br=[0.12 0.56 0.45 0.67 0.89]; % broadening parameter for each wavelength
T=[101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110];% temperature for 10 layers
wlall=linspace(50,550,40);%all the wavelength in 50um to 550 um range

% x is defined as,
%(br*wl/(br*br + (wlall-wl)^2))*br;
%If I do a calculation for the first line 
((br(1)*T(1)*wl(1))./(br(1)*br(1)*(T(1)) + (wlall(:)-wl(1)).^2))*br(1)*T(1)


%Now I'm going to calculate it for all the lines in the first layer
k= repmat(wlall,5,1);


for i=1:5;
       kn(i,:)=(br(i)*T(1)* wl(i)./(br(i)*br(i)*T(1) + (k(i,:)- 
       wl(i)).^2))*br(i)*T(1);

end


%Above code gives me x parameter for all the wavelengths in the
%given range( 50 to 550 um) in the first layer, dimension is (5,40)

% I need only the maximum value of each column

an=(kn(:,:)');
[ll,mm]=sort(an,2,'descend');
vn=(ll(:,1))'
```

%Now my output has the dimension , (1,40) one is for the first layer, 40 is
   %for the maximum x parameter corresponding to each wavelength in first layer
   %Now I want to calculate the x parameter in all 10 layers,So T should vary 
   %from T(1) to T(10) and get the
   %maximum in each column, so my output should have the dimension ( 10, 40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to run an extra 'for' loop for each value of 'T'. Here is an example:

```
            clc; close all; clear all; 

            wl=[100 200 300 400 500]; %5 wavelengths, 5 spectral lines 
            br=[0.12 0.56 0.45 0.67 0.89]; % broadening parameter for each wavelength
            T=[101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110];% temperature for 10 layers
            wlall=linspace(50,550,40);%all the wavelength in 50um to 550 um range

            % x is defined as,
            %(br*wl/(br*br + (wlall-wl)^2))*br;
            %If I do a calculation for the first line 
            ((br(1)*T(1)*wl(1))./(br(1)*br(1)*(T(1)) + (wlall(:)-wl(1)).^2))*br(1)*T(1)


            %Now I'm going to calculate it for all the lines in the first layer
            k= repmat(wlall,5,1);

            for index = 1:numel(T)


                for i=1:5

                       kn(i,:, index)=(br(i)*T(index)* wl(i)./(br(i)*br(i)*T(index) + (k(i,:)- wl(i)).^2))*br(i)*T(index);

                end

                an(:, :, index) = transpose(kn(:, :, index));

                vn(:, index) = max(an(:, :, index), [], 2);

            end

            vn = transpose(vn);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nash. I'm grateful to you.